# How do I change to whole number instead of % in this codepen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently, I happen to come to this page.
I realise the change of the code happen in this function.
And it take data from `<tr><td>A</td><td>1</td><td style="background-color:#336699">&nbsp;</td></tr>` .

 If the data in `<td>` is whole number, it does not have much effect like what % give.

How do I make it accept whole number and provide the effect similar to %?

```
function viewGraph() {
  $(".column").css("height", "0");
  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
    var ha = $(this).children("td").eq(1).text();
    $("#col" + index)
      .animate({ height: ha }, 1500)
      .html("<div>" + ha + "</div>");
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  viewGraph();
});
```

https://codepen.io/bobasdasd/pen/bRNzza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add this to your code and it should work the way you want it to

```
if(!ha.includes("%")) {
  ha = ha + "%";
}
```

Applied to your code:

```
function viewGraph() {
  $(".column").css("height", "0");
  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
    var ha = $(this).children("td").eq(1).text();

    // Simply add this.
    if(!ha.includes("%")) {
      ha = ha + "%";
    }

    $("#col" + index)
      .animate({ height: ha }, 1500)
      .html("<div>" + ha + "</div>");
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  viewGraph();
});
```

Hopefully this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

This function take the text inside `td` and set column height equal that text. So, if the text have `%`, the column height will be setted in `%`. If the text is just a number, the column height will be setted in `px`. So, increasing your number (replace 1 by 100 or bigger), you will see the effect. If you want convert number to `%`, just do this:

```
if(ha.indexOf('%')==-1) ha+='%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function viewGraph() {
  var height = $("#grafico").height() / 4;
  $(".column").css("height", "0");
  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
  var ha = $(this).children("td").eq(1).text();
  $("#col" + index)
    .animate({ height: (+ha ? ha * height : ha ) }, 1500)
    .html("<div>" + ha + "</div>");
  });
}


                                                ---- A poor English speaker
```

Comment: describe your answer little bit

Comment: Calculate the height of the container，Divided by four gradients， ha * (the height of the gradient)，表示不知道我描述了你看不看的懂啊~  很闹心.